# How do I update the list after adding new element

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm making this login system and I want new username to be added to the existing list and then save it there.

Code:

```
def login():

usernames = ["username1", "username2", "username3"]
passwords = ["pass1", "pass2", "pass3"]

print("Login")

username = input("Username: ")
if username not in usernames:
    print("User doesn't exist")
    input("Make an account? ")
    if "yes":
        print("Account Setup")
        new_username = input("Username: ")
        usernames.append(new_username)
        print(usernames)
        new_password = input("Password: ")
        passwords.append(new_password)
        print(passwords)
        login()
    else:
        sys.exit()

else:
    password = input("Password: ")
    if password not in passwords:
        print("Incorrect password")
        login()
    elif usernames[0] != passwords[0]:
        print("Incorrect password")
        login()
    elif usernames[1] != passwords[1]:
        print("Incorrect password")
        login()
    elif usernames[2] != passwords[2]:
        print("Incorrect password")
        login()
```

When I add new user their info is saved but when login() here is used and the login process starts again the input data is lost, the account i just created doesn't exist anymore.

```
if "yes":
        print("Account Setup")
        new_username = input("Username: ")
        usernames.append(new_username)
        print(usernames)
        new_password = input("Password: ")
        passwords.append(new_password)
        print(passwords)
        login()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. It helps to provide a [mre], so that the problem is more obvious both to yourself and to people answering. By the way your code is full of other problems, for example the indentation is wrong, duplicate usernames are allowed, and your password validation is all wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call the login function you are setting password and username variable back to  start. In this line:

```
usernames = ["username1", "username2", "username3"]
passwords = ["pass1", "pass2", "pass3"]
```

If you put those lines out of the function it will work.

BTW:

Don`t use two lists for passwords and usernames. It is inefficient and unnecessarily complicated. Use a dictionary. Like this:

```
logins = {"Jack": 1234, "Paul": 4321}
```

If you want two add new logins use:

```
logins["Oliver"] = 7531
```

If you want to check if username exists:

```
if "Jack" in logins:
    print("Jack is a username")
```

Check if password is correct:

```
if logins[username] == inputed_password:
    print("Password is correct.")
```

Note:

All of these names and passwords are made up. You can use any you want.

Comment: Always glad to help. :) Please upvote if it helped a lot.

Comment: I would upvote but I dont have enough reputation, I just joined the website :/

Comment: OK. Thanks anyway! Good luck!